# Upload/Download large file from spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, aws-lambda, architecture, aws-glue

I have spring boot application that is responsible for uploading/downloading data in the Excel CSV format to/from the database.For the few records it worked perfectly fine but as records are more than 1 million than this is consuming lots of memory and lots of time.

Any suggestions so that we can download the records fast and with efficient memory performance.

Solution tried: Changed Apache POI to SXSSF, this reduces the memory consumption but still it blocks the memory for the long(several hours).

Another approach we are trying to make AWS lambda function where this processing should be delegated and memory of application will not be affected.

Comment: Hello, there is a Spring framework called Spring Batch. It's exactly for your use case: reading from CSV file and writing to a database. It works with configurable chunks so you can even process GB of data. Like read 10k records and write them out then get next 10k.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're on the right track with using the SXSSF API from Apache POI to reduce memory consumption. However, since you're still experiencing long processing times, you may want to consider optimizing your application's performance further by following these suggestions:

1. **Use pagination:** Instead of retrieving all records at once, consider retrieving them in smaller chunks, or "pages," using pagination. This can help reduce memory consumption and processing time, especially when dealing with large datasets. You can use the LIMIT and OFFSET clauses in your SQL queries to achieve this.
2. **Use multithreading:** To further improve performance, you can consider using multithreading to process multiple pages of data simultaneously. This can help reduce processing time by utilizing multiple CPU cores and improving overall throughput.
3. **Use indexing:** If your database supports indexing, consider indexing the columns that you frequently query or sort on. This can help improve query performance and reduce the time it takes to retrieve data.
4. **Consider AWS RDS Aurora:** If you're using Amazon Web Services (AWS), consider using AWS RDS Aurora instead of a traditional database. Aurora is a high-performance, scalable, and fully managed relational database service that is optimized for the cloud. It is designed to handle large datasets and high traffic loads, which may be more suitable for your use case.
5. **Use a streaming approach:** Instead of downloading all records at once, consider using a streaming approach to download data in smaller chunks. This can help reduce memory consumption and processing time, as well as improve the user experience by displaying data in real time.
6. **Use caching:** Consider caching frequently accessed data in memory to improve performance. This can help reduce the number of database queries and improve the response time for your application.

Regarding your idea of using AWS Lambda to delegate processing, it can be a good solution for offloading processing from your application server and reducing memory usage. However, keep in mind that there may be additional costs and complexity involved with setting up and managing a Lambda function.